# Can't change XMPP MUC description in Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to change MUC description with these stanza

```
<iq from='user@example.com' to='group@conference.example.com' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='4fd8ab1b-75e2-4488-a299-124a5e0aa8a3:sendIQ'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner'><x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'><field var='muc#roominfo_description'><value>description</value></field></x></query></iq>
```

Server replies with these

```
<error xmlns="jabber:client" code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" xml:lang="en">Unknown field 'muc#roominfo_description' of type 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#roomconfig'</text></error>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Ejabberd 18.06
CentOS 6

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using wrong Attribute in your xml.

Just replace
`<field var='muc#roominfo_description`
to
`<field var='muc#roomconfig_roomdesc`

and you are done :)